# Jenkins - running batch files that are calling other batch files

Tags: c#, batch-file, jenkins, project, jobs

I'm trying to create a Freestyle project in Jenkins in order to run a batch file. This batch file is calling other batch files, one of them with parameters. This is the file:

```
call setBuildFolders.bat
cd %BUILD_SCRIPTS%
call buildProd.bat gb cs
```

Even if I specify in this file the folder as well (something like `C:\S12 V4.5\AutoBuild`), it still doesn't work, especially the second one (`buildProd`) that has parameters. This second batch also calls another batch file, with parameters, and git and Visual Studio to build the solution.
Having all of the source and batch files in the workspace doesn't help.
Is there any way to make it work?

Thank you.

Comment: How  "doesn't it work"? Is `buildProd.bat` in `%BUILD_SCRIPTS%`? Are all of your files on the same drive? Any errormessages?

Comment: Other than a potential lack of doublequotes, ```Call "setBuildFolders.bat"```, ```CD /D "%BUILD_SCRIPTS%"```, ```Call "buildProd.bat" "gb" "cs"```, and no idea what your variable value is, _(if it holds a fully qualified absolute path)_, you have not submitted code which exhibits a reproducible issue. Please explain to us exactly how C#, git, and Visual Studio is involved here, then provide the full and exact content of your Jenkins code, together with every single batch file, so that we can fully understand and recreate your method, environment and reported issue. **Please also read [mcve].**

Comment: The following has the (partial) content of the batch files, which work fine in Windows but not in Jenkins.
Regarding the tags, I just put some because a minimum of 5 were required. The purpose of these batch files
is to use git for updating the local code and then to build the solution using devenv. I will put 3 comments
since one is too long. This is part 1.

setBuildFolders.bat has code like:  
SET BUILD_SCRIPTS=C:\S12 V4.5\Build Scripts
SET BUILD_SOURCE=C:\S12 V4.5\Source
SET BUILD_DEST_CLIENT="C:\S12 V4.5\bin\Client"

Comment: Part 2:
buildProd.bat has code like:
@echo off
REM %1 = Operations
REM gbp = Git, Build, Package
REM gb  = Git, Build
REM bp  = Build, Package
REM b   = Build
REM p   = Package

REM %2 = ClientServer
REM s = server
REM c = client
REM sc or cs = server and client
 
REM %3 = BUILD Output file   

call setBuildFolders.bat

Comment: rem ...................................................
 
if NOT "%1"=="" GOTO ServerClient
rem %1=gbp

:ServerClient
if NOT "%2"=="" GOTO BuildInfo 
rem %2=sc

:BuildInfo
SET BuildInfoFile=%3
if NOT "%BuildInfoFile%"=="" GOTO Git 
SET BuildInfoFile=%BUILD_LOG%\Build.txt 

:Git
echo --------------- Start Process for Options: %1 %2 -----------------
echo --------------- Start Process for Options: %1 %2 ----------------- > %BuildInfoFile%

if "%1"=="gbp"  GOTO DoGit 
if "%1"=="gb"   GOTO DoGit 
if "%1"=="g"    GOTO DoGit 
GOTO Build

Comment: Part 4:
:DoGit
ECHO Get the last version from Git ...
cd %BUILD_SOURCE%
git pull
cd %BUILD_SCRIPTS%


:Build
if "%1"=="gbp"  GOTO DoBuild 
if "%1"=="gb"   GOTO DoBuild 
if "%1"=="bp"   GOTO DoBuild 
if "%1"=="b"    GOTO DoBuild 
GOTO Package

Comment: Part 5:
:DoBuild
REM Rebuild the solution
REM !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!call CopyProjectFiles !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
if "%2"=="s"    GOTO DoBuildServer 
if "%2"=="sc"   GOTO DoBuildServer 
if "%2"=="cs"   GOTO DoBuildServer 
GOTO BuildClient
:DoBuildServer
call buildSolution txServerS12.sln "Release|Any CPU" %BuildInfoFile%

Comment: Part 6:
:BuildClient
if "%2"=="c"    GOTO DoBuildClient 
if "%2"=="sc"   GOTO DoBuildClient 
if "%2"=="cs"   GOTO DoBuildClient 
GOTO Package
:DoBuildClient
call buildSolution txClientS12.sln "Release|x86" %BuildInfoFile%

buildSolution.bat has the following code:
echo off
REM Build the solution
REM %1 = Solution file
REM %2 = Configuration name
REM %3 = Build Output file

Comment: Part 7:
call setBuildFolders.bat

echo.                               
echo ----------------------------------------------------------
echo ---------------------------------------------------------- >> %3
echo - Start Clean-up %1...
echo - Start Clean-up %1... >> %3

REM CleanUp here
SET Solution="%BUILD_SOURCE%\%1"
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv" /clean %2 %Solution% >> %3

echo ----------------------------------------------------------
echo ---------------------------------------------------------- >> %3

Comment: Part 8:
echo - End Clean-up %1.
echo - End Clean-up %1. >> %3
echo.                              
echo.                              
echo ----------------------------------------------------------
echo ---------------------------------------------------------- >> %3
echo - Start Build %1...
echo - Start Build %1... >> %3

REM Build Here
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv" /build %2 %Solution% >> %3

echo ---------------------------------------------------------- >> %3
echo - End Build %1.

Comment: As you can see, comments are not the best place to put code. Please edit your question with your code to make it readable. Nobody wants to decrypt those comments.

Comment: I looked at the help and I still don't know how to add the code (it would be from 3 batch files). I split it because it was saying the comment was too long.

Comment: Click on the word "Edit" below your question, insert your code, mark it and press the `{}` button above the edit window to format it as code.

Comment: I finally figured it out. I had to put my batch files in the workspace and do a cd %WORKSPACE%\Build Scripts and the run it from there. They will be built in a different place, not in the workspace, but Jenkins was looking for them (the ones called by the main batch file) in the workspace.